# Does Azure Managed Identity support on-prem MS SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-managed-identity

**Update**

Azure Functions need to access on-prem MS SQL Databases via Azure Managed Identity.

Does Azure Managed Identity support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Managed identities allows Azure resources to authenticate or authorize themselves with other supported Azure resources.

On-Premise MS SQL Server supports two authentication modes, Windows authentication mode and mixed mode.

Azure Managed Identity does not support your case - Azure Function connection to On-Premise MS SQL Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/authentication-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15